# Cordova angular application camera does not work on first run after granting permission to camera

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Im using cordova version 11.
The problem is that on first app run i ask for permission and after granting permission im not getting the video sources in my phone.

**My package.json(cordova section alone)**

```
  "cordova": {
"platforms": [
  "browser",
  "android"
],
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {
    "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
    "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {}
}
}
```

**In my app component**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.action.isReady.subscribe((res: any) => {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    
    function onDeviceReady() {
    var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
    permissions.hasPermission(permissions.CAMERA, function( status:any ){
      if ( status.hasPermission ) {
        console.log("Yes :D ");
      }
      else {
        permissions.requestPermission(permissions.CAMERA, success, error);

        function error() {
          console.warn('Camera permission is not turned on');
        }

        function success( status:any ) {
          if( !status.hasPermission ) error();
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("navigator.geolocation works well");
  }
});
```

}

***On calling handle function after granting permissions, no camera sources are available, but after closing and opening the app, i get the front and back camera's listed.***

```
public handle(action: any, fn: string): void {
  const playDeviceFacingBack = (devices: any[]) => {
  // front camera or back camera check here!
  const device = devices.find(f => (/back|rear|environment/gi.test(f.label))); // Default Back Facing Camera
  action.playDevice(device ? device.deviceId : devices[0].deviceId);
}

 if (fn === 'start') {
  action[fn](playDeviceFacingBack).subscribe((r: any) => console.log(fn, r), alert);
 } else {
  action[fn]().subscribe((r: any) => console.log(fn, r), alert);
 }
```

}

**My config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.cordova.camera" 
version="1.0.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<name>CordovaCameraApp</name>
<description>Sample Apache Cordova App</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    </config-file>
 </platform>
```

**Generated AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.cordova.plugin.camera.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="32" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:scheme="content" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
```

***I have tried many solutions , none have worked so far, any help would be appreciated***